# sudo: a terminal is required to read the password;

Tags: sudo

When running a command `doc2pdf` sometimes this error is returned

> sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S
> option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
> sudo: a password is required

But I have already done this to prevent it? But still get the error

```
# sudo visudo
www-data    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf
```

Comment: From my understanding you should add `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf` or `www-data ALL=/usr/bin/doc2pdf NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf` to avoid password

Comment: The syntax is correct, so there must be something else going on

Comment: Why does this need `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: @Panki To keep the reading and writing that the `www-data` user does in apache I presume in apache.  Having no security would allow web visitors to possibly pass malicious code to the `doc2pdf` converter.  This prevents inadvertent privilege escalation.

Comment: I'm with @Panki - the security model looks all wrong here. If the data is meant to be accessed by the webserver, then it should be accessible to the webserver uid.

Comment: @symcbean the "correct" solution would IMO be to add the user to the `www-data` group I believe, but I don't think I really understand the problem.